# ACL not working for some controller which have upload component & imageresize component in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, components, acl

My cakephp version is 1.3.10, I have added acl component for assign authorize policy.

Its working fine for all controller. But in two controller I have added Upload component (For upload files) and Image Resize component (For resize image)

```
var $components = array('Upload','ImageResize');
```

When i try to access my controller `AffiliatesController` and `AwardsController` it going in loop and i get error: page is not redirect properly.

If i commented those component then its working fine. Can anyone suggest me what is the issue?

My acl controller is looks like below,

```
<?php
class AclController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Aco';
    var $components = array('Acl');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }

    function build_aco() {
        error_reporting(0);

        if (!Configure::read('debug')) {
            return $this->_stop();
        }

        $log = array();
        $aco = $this->Acl->Aco;
        $root = $aco->node('controllers');

        if (!$root) {
            $aco->create(array('parent_id' => null, 'model' => null, 'alias' => 'controllers'));
            $root = $aco->save();
            $root['Aco']['id'] = $aco->id;
            $log[] = 'Created Aco node for controllers';
        } else {
            $root = $root[0];
        }

        App::import('Core', 'File');
        $Controllers = App::objects('controller');
        $appIndex = array_search('App', $Controllers);

        if ($appIndex !== false ) {
            unset($Controllers[$appIndex]);
        }

        $baseMethods = get_class_methods('Controller');
        $baseMethods[] = 'build_acl';
        $Plugins = $this->_getPluginControllerNames();
        $Controllers = array_merge($Controllers, $Plugins);

        // look at each controller in app/controllers
        foreach ($Controllers as $ctrlName) {
            $methods = $this->_getClassMethods($this->_getPluginControllerPath($ctrlName));

            // Do all Plugins First
            if ($this->_isPlugin($ctrlName)){
                $pluginNode = $aco->node('controllers/'.$this->_getPluginName($ctrlName));

                if (!$pluginNode) {
                    $aco->create(array('parent_id' => $root['Aco']['id'], 'model' => null, 'alias' => $this->_getPluginName($ctrlName)));
                    $pluginNode = $aco->save();
                    $pluginNode['Aco']['id'] = $aco->id;
                    $log[] = 'Created Aco node for ' . $this->_getPluginName($ctrlName) . ' Plugin';
                }
            }

            // find / make controller node
            $controllerNode = $aco->node('controllers/'.$ctrlName);
            if (!$controllerNode) {
                if ($this->_isPlugin($ctrlName)){
                    $pluginNode = $aco->node('controllers/' . $this->_getPluginName($ctrlName));
                    $aco->create(array('parent_id' => $pluginNode['0']['Aco']['id'], 'model' => null, 'alias' => $this->_getPluginControllerName($ctrlName)));
                    $controllerNode = $aco->save();
                    $controllerNode['Aco']['id'] = $aco->id;
                    $log[] = 'Created Aco node for ' . $this->_getPluginControllerName($ctrlName) . ' ' . $this->_getPluginName($ctrlName) . ' Plugin Controller';
                } else {
                    $aco->create(array('parent_id' => $root['Aco']['id'], 'model' => null, 'alias' => $ctrlName));
                    $controllerNode = $aco->save();
                    $controllerNode['Aco']['id'] = $aco->id;
                    $log[] = 'Created Aco node for ' . $ctrlName;
                }
            } else {

                $controllerNode = $controllerNode[0];
            }

            //clean the methods. to remove those in Controller and private actions.
            foreach ($methods as $k => $method) {
                if (strpos($method, '_', 0) === 0) {
                    unset($methods[$k]);
                    continue;
                }

                if (in_array($method, $baseMethods)) {
                unset($methods[$k]);
                continue;
                }

                $methodNode = $aco->node('controllers/'.$ctrlName.'/'.$method);
                if (!$methodNode) {
                    $aco->create(array('parent_id' => $controllerNode['Aco']['id'], 'model' => null, 'alias' => $method));
                    $methodNode = $aco->save();
                    $log[] = 'Created Aco node for '. $method;
                }
            }
        }

        if(count($log)>0) {
            debug($log);
        }

        exit;
    }

    function _getClassMethods($ctrlName = null) {
        App::import('Controller', $ctrlName);
        if (strlen(strstr($ctrlName, '.')) > 0) {
            // plugin's controller
            $num = strpos($ctrlName, '.');
            $ctrlName = substr($ctrlName, $num+1);
        }

        $ctrlclass = $ctrlName . 'Controller';
        $methods = get_class_methods($ctrlclass);

        // Add scaffold defaults if scaffolds are being used
        $properties = get_class_vars($ctrlclass);
        if (array_key_exists('scaffold',$properties)) {
            if($properties['scaffold'] == 'admin') {
                $methods = array_merge($methods, array('admin_add', 'admin_edit', 'admin_index', 'admin_view', 'admin_delete'));
            } else {
                $methods = array_merge($methods, array('add', 'edit', 'index', 'view', 'delete'));
            }
        }

        return $methods;
    }

    function _isPlugin($ctrlName = null) {
        $arr = String::tokenize($ctrlName, '/');
        if (count($arr) > 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _getPluginControllerPath($ctrlName = null) {
        $arr = String::tokenize($ctrlName, '/');
        if (count($arr) == 2) {
            return $arr[0] . '.' . $arr[1];
        } else {
            return $arr[0];
        }
    }

    function _getPluginName($ctrlName = null) {
        $arr = String::tokenize($ctrlName, '/');
        if (count($arr) == 2) {
            return $arr[0];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _getPluginControllerName($ctrlName = null) {
        $arr = String::tokenize($ctrlName, '/');
        if (count($arr) == 2) {
            return $arr[1];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Get the names of the plugin controllers ...
    *
    * This function will get an array of the plugin controller names, and
    * also makes sure the controllers are available for us to get the
    * method names by doing an App::import for each plugin controller.
    *
    * @return array of plugin names.
    *
    */
    function _getPluginControllerNames() {
        App::import('Core', 'File', 'Folder');
        $paths = Configure::getInstance();
        $folder =& new Folder();
        $folder->cd(APP . 'plugins');

        // Get the list of plugins
        $Plugins = $folder->read();
        $Plugins = $Plugins[0];
        $arr = array();

        // Loop through the plugins
        foreach($Plugins as $pluginName) {
            // Change directory to the plugin
            $didCD = $folder->cd(APP . 'plugins'. DS . $pluginName . DS . 'controllers');
            // Get a list of the files that have a file name that ends
            // with controller.php
            $files = $folder->findRecursive('.*_controller\.php');
            // Loop through the controllers we found in the plugins directory
            foreach($files as $fileName) {
                // Get the base file name
                $file = basename($fileName);
                // Get the controller name
                $file = Inflector::camelize(substr($file, 0, strlen($file)-strlen('_controller.php')));

                if (!preg_match('/^'. Inflector::humanize($pluginName). 'App/', $file)) {
                    if (!App::import('Controller', $pluginName.'.'.$file)) {
                        debug('Error importing '.$file.' for plugin '.$pluginName);
                    } else {
                        /// Now prepend the Plugin name ...
                        // This is required to allow us to fetch the method names.
                        $arr[] = Inflector::humanize($pluginName) . "/" . $file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #echo "<pre>";
        #print_r ($arr);exit;

        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up permissions, To allow ARO's access to ACO's
     */
    function build_permission() {
        $group =& $this->User->Group;

        //Allow developers to everything
        $group->id = 1;
        $this->Acl->allow(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 1), 'controllers');

        //Allow administrator to everything except "Admin Groups", "Payment Gateways"
        $group->id = 2;
        $this->Acl->allow(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2), 'controllers');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Groups');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Users/view');
        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Users/add');
        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Users/edit');
        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Users/delete');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Staticpages');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Cmstags');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Cmstagpositions');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Cmspages');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Emailtemplates');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Affiliates');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Awards');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Faqs');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Newsletters');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Newslettersubscribers');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Packages');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Transactions');

        $this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 2),  'controllers/Testimonials');

        //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
        echo "all done";
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I have checked it, its my mistake for UploadComponent. Its copied from cakephp 1.2.7 version and I used cakephp 1.3.10 version. In 1.2.7 version component defined like class UploadComponent extends Component and In 1.3.10 version component defined like class UploadComponent extends Object. So, i have changed code and its working fine for me